# Cross Origin Resource Sharing in Tomcat

Tags: html

This [Html5 rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-cors) talks about Cross Origin Resource Sharing, I would like to know how to set it up on my tomcat server, or can I specify it for only one application running on my web server without affecting other applications??